# NSData to NSString converstion problem!

Tags: iphone, objective-c, encoding, nsstring, nsdata

I'm getting an html file as NSData and need to parse it to extract some info. My approach was to convert it to NSString with UTF8 encoding (the html has non english characters, russian for example) - it failed. I used something like that:

```
NSString *respData = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[theData bytes]];
```

but it returned nil.

The only thing that actually worked was

```
[NSString stringWithCString:[theData bytes] length:[theData length]];
```

but when it encounters russian characters for example it returns jibrish.

Then my next approach was to parse the byte array of the data, extract the bytes I need and somehow convert them to NSString. I tried something like that:

```
-(NSString *)UTF8StringFromData:(NSData *)theData{
 Byte *arr = [theData bytes];
 NSUInteger begin1 = [self findIndexOf:@"<li>" bArr:arr size:[theData length]]+4;
 NSUInteger end1 = [self findIndexOf:@"</li></ol>" bArr:arr size:[theData length]];
 Byte *arr1 = (Byte *)malloc(sizeof(Byte)*((end1-begin1+1)));
 int j = 0;
 for (int i = begin1; i < end1; i++){
  arr1[j] = arr[i];
  j++;
 }
 arr1[j]='\0';
 NSData *temp = [NSData dataWithBytes:arr1 length:j];
 return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:temp encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

Comment: Are you *sure* that the file is encoded as UTF-8, and not as ISO 8859-5 or something?

Answer (score 11):

Supposing you got a NSURLResponse* response and an NSData* data:

```
CFStringEncoding cfEncoding = CFStringConvertIANACharSetNameToEncoding((CFStringRef) [response textEncodingName]);
NSStringEncoding encoding = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(cfEncoding);

NSString* string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:encoding];

// Do stuff here..

[string release];
```

Comment: I'm using xcode 4 with ARC enabled for my project, and when I use the above code it complains that `Cast of Objective-C pointer type 'NSString *' to C pointer type 'CFStringRef' (aka 'const struct __CFString *') requires a bridged cast`. When I implemented any of the suggested fixes (using either `__bridge` or `__bridge_retained`) I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS signal when the program runs. Any ideas?

Comment: It should be `(__bridge CFStringRef) [response textEncodingName]`. That neither works indicates to me that the problem lies elsewhere. Turn on NSZombieEnabled and use CFZombieLevel to track down the deallocated memory access.

Comment: thanks for the reply. That sounds rather complicated and I'm a total noob in iOS development, but I'll check it out. I eventually worked around the problem by using the horrible code: `char* myenc = malloc([responseEncoding length]);
        [[_response textEncodingName] getCString:myenc maxLength:[responseEncoding length] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        CFStringRef encenc = CFStringCreateWithCString(kCFAllocatorDefault, myenc, kCFStringEncodingASCII);
        CFStringEncoding cfEncoding = CFStringConvertIANACharSetNameToEncoding(encenc);
        free(myenc);`

Answer (score 1):

I'm responding to the Martijn Thé thread above, here, as I couldn't put a readable code snippet in the comments.

I found that if on the server , the response content type is set to 'text/plain', then (__bridge CFStringRef) [response textEncodingName] will be null, and if you try to pass this to CFStringConvertIANACharSetNameToEncoding you will get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS signal.

If the content type of the response is set to 'text/html; charset=utf-8', then everything works as expected. To handle the 'text/plain' content type, this is what I did:

`CFStringRef sRef = (__bridge CFStringRef)[response textEncodingName];
if (sRef)
{
        CFStringEncoding cfEncoding = CFStringConvertIANACharSetNameToEncoding(sRef);
        encoding = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(cfEncoding);
}
else
{
        encoding = NSASCIIStringEncoding;
}`

Answer (score 0):

First of all here is my code

```
-(NSString *)UTF8StringFromData:(NSData *)theData{
    Byte *arr = [theData bytes];
    NSUInteger begin1 = [self findIndexOf:@"<li>" bArr:arr size:[theData length]]+4;
    NSUInteger end1 = [self findIndexOf:@"</li></ol>" bArr:arr size:[theData length]];
    Byte *arr1 = (Byte *)malloc(sizeof(Byte)*((end1-begin1+1)));
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = begin1; i < end1; i++){
        arr1[j] = arr[i];
        j++;
    }
    arr1[j]='\0';
    NSData *temp = [NSData dataWithBytes:arr1 length:j];
    return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:temp encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];  
}
```

and second - I am getting the file contents from the web - so I can't be sure about anything. It's an html of a google translation if it helps...

Comment: no one knows? ... come on... Someone must have come across this before