# Conversion of NSData to NSString fails due to some charecters

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, encoding, nsstring

I am converting `NSData` to `NSString` which I got as response of a url using the following method.

```
NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:_Data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

It works fine and I am using this for a long time but today I faced an issue while loading the data (paging) at one page my result gives `null` string.

So I searched SO and found a method from this link [NSData to NSString converstion problem!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1409537/1271057)

```
[NSString stringWithCString:[theData bytes] length:[theData length]];
```

and this works fine.

My queries,

1. The method was deprecated in iOS 2.0. If I use this will I be facing any issue in future?
2. I think this is the text that made the method fail [image]  What is this and is there any way that I can encode this using `NSUTF8StringEncoding`?
3. What is the the alternative encoding that I can use for encoding all the type of characters like in the above pic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If

```
NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:_Data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

returns `nil` then `_Data` does not contain a valid string in UTF-8 encoding.

You said that

```
[NSString stringWithCString:[theData bytes] length:[theData length]];
```

works fine in your case. This method
interprets the data bytes in the "default C string encoding", but it is unspecified which
encoding that is (and therefore this method is deprecated and should *not* be used).

I *think* the default C string encoding is still "Mac Roman". In that case

```
NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:_Data encoding:NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding];
```

would be the correct solution. But in any case, you should find out which encoding
the web service uses for the response, and specify that in the `initWithData:encoding:`
method.

Comment: the server is not using any encoding. I just find it now. does making the server to use the utf8 encoding will solve the problem

Comment: @vamsi575kg: Yes, making the server use UTF-8 makes much sense, if you have that option.

Comment: @vamsi575kg In any case, the server should setup a proper `Content-Type` header. The content-type header specifies the kind of content (e.g. image, text, etc.) and other properties, possibly a "charset" when the content is text.

Comment: @MartinR `NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding` is very likely to be incorrect, since a server which sent the data has no knowledge what would be the default encoding of the current platform string implementation of the receiver ;)

Comment: @CouchDeveloper: That what just a guess, based on the OP's statement that it works fine with `stringWithCString`. I just tested it: that method actually uses the good old Mac Roman encoding.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, NSString may use that encoding, but that is irrelevant. What's needed is the encoding of the byte stream sent from the server. This is how `NSString` should then interpret the byte sequence when it is created.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper: OP said that calling `[NSString stringWithCString:...]` with the data from the server returns the *correct result*. If that is the case, then the server must have sent the data in Mac Roman encoding.

Answer (score 4):

In order to obtain the type of the content which is sent by the server, you need to inspect the `Content-Type` header of the response.

The content type's value specifies a "MIMI type", e.g.:

`Content-Type: text/plain`

A Content-Type's value may additionally specify a character encoding, e.g.:

`Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8`

Each MIME type *should* define a "default" charset, which is to be used when there is no charset parameter specified.

For `text/*` media types the default charset is US-ASCII.
(see [RFC 6657, §3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6657)).

The following code snippet demonstrates how to safely encode the *body* of a response:

```
    - (NSString*) bodyString {
        CFStringEncoding cfEncoding = NSASCIIStringEncoding;
        NSString* textEncodingName = self.response.textEncodingName;
        if (textEncodingName) {
            cfEncoding = CFStringConvertIANACharSetNameToEncoding( (__bridge CFStringRef)(textEncodingName) );
        }
        if (cfEncoding != kCFStringEncodingInvalidId) {
            NSStringEncoding encoding = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(cfEncoding);
            return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.body encoding:encoding];
        }        
        else {
            return [self.body description];
        }
    }
```

Note:

`body` is a property returning a `NSData` object representing the response data.

`response` is a property returning the `NSHTTPURLResponse` object.

Comment: That's a good general solution, I did not know CFStringConvertIANACharSetNameToEncoding() yet!

Comment: An even better solution would take into account the former, now obsolete, default encoding of text* media types: [ISO-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1). That is, when no charset is specified and US-ASCII fails, one might try ISO-8859-1, before falling back to raw binary.

Comment: Why not try ISO-8859-1 (aka NSISOLatin1StringEncoding) first (if no charset is specified)? As I understand it, this is an extension of US-ASCII, and a conversion of an arbitrary byte stream never fails, because all bytes 0x00 .. 0xFF are mapped to the corresponding character in U+00 .. U+FF.

Comment: Yes, this is a valid option - as with any other US-ASCII compatible encoding (UTF-8). Whether you want to do it or not, only depends on the subsequent "string processor" which may only understand US-ASCII. If you want to just display or log it to the console, you can certainly encode it with ISO-8858-1 or UTF-8 (or alternatively, use "lossy ASCII conversion"). Otherwise, if you want to check whether the data is indeed US-ASCII, you may return `nil` if it is not. And, finally, if you need that byte stream unaltered (say for a parser), just use the NSData object, and no NSString.

Comment: Thank you @CouchDeveloper sure i will try this solution. for now I made the server user utf-8 encoded. +1 for your ans

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
NSString *theString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"To be continued%C", ellipsis];

NSData *asciiData = [theString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSString *asciiString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:asciiData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

NSLog(@"Original: %@ (length %d)", theString, [theString length]);
NSLog(@"Converted: %@ (length %d)", asciiString, [asciiString length]);
```

Comment: this would convert it to ASCII, not UTF8

Answer (score 0):

It is due to the uncorrect string encoding.
You can try:

1. save the `NSData` to the disk with `dataPath`
2. use the `NSString` class method to create the string:

```
+ (id)stringWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)url usedEncoding:(NSStringEncoding *)enc error:(NSError **)error
```

Notice here:

> enc
>
> Upon return, if url is read successfully, contains the encoding used to interpret the data.

So if the method successes, you can get the correct string and all is done by the iOS.